# Positioning nav on lower header border with overlapping divs (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple web page consisting of three divs: A header div containing an image, a content div containing text and a nav div containing the nav elements and a logo. My goal is to overlap the header div with the nav div so that the nav elements and the logo are always positioned vertically centered on the lower border of the header div.

Here's my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <style>
          body {
            text-align: center;
          }

          #headerimage {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 50;
            position: relative;
          }

          #headerimage > img {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            border: 6px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #671013;
            }

          #nav {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: visible;
            top: 97.75%;
            z-index: 100;
            position: absolute;
          }

          #nav > img {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-top: -6.2%;
            height: 20%;
            width: 20%;
          }

          .nav-element {
            width: 10%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            border: 4px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #2d3139;
            background-color: white;
            color: #80857f;
          }

          .nav-element:hover {
            background-color: #2d3139;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
          }

          .left {
            float: left;
            z-index: 100;
          }

          .first {
            margin-left: 3%;
          }

          .right {
            float: right;
            z-index: 100;
          }

          .last {
            margin-right: 3%;
          }

          #point2 {
            margin-left: 9%;
          }

          #point3 {
            margin-right: 9%;
          }

          #content {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
          }

          #text {
            padding-top: 8%;
            padding-left: 3%;
            padding-right: 3%;
            padding-bottom: 5%;
            text-align: justify center;
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
          }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
  <div id="headerimage">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/34577/pexels-photo.jpg" alt="Headerimage" />

    <div id="nav">
        <div id="point1" class="nav-element left first">
          Point 1
        </div>

      <div id="point2" class="nav-element left ">
        Point 2
      </div>
      
      <img src="https://pixabay.com/get/55e2d3454853a814f1dc8460da2932771736dfe6575074_640.png" alt="Logo" />
    
      <div id="point3" class="nav-element right last">
        Point 3
      </div>

      <div id="point4" class="nav-element right">
        Point 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="text">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim 
        ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut 
        aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit 
        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur 
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
        mollit anim id est laborum.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently the nav div doesn't stay centered on the lower border and my online researches haven't brought any useful results so far, so if anyone has an idea to point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: When doesn't it stay centered? When you resize the screen?

Comment: Yes, I tried using margins with percentages but no success so far

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you want:

```css
nav img {
    margin-top: -40px;
}
#point1, #point2, #point3, #point4 {
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Fine-tune the margin as fits.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but thanks for that, setting a `margin-top` for the four point elements has helped